# Profiling a Laravel beanstalkd queue using Blackfire.io

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, beanstalkd, blackfire

Suppose I have the following Laravel 4.2 queuing code that runs on the beanstalkd queue service:

```
Queue::push('Reporter\ImportReportData', ['report_request_id' => $id], 'import-reports');
```

Is there a way I could have the execution of this analyzed by the Blackfire.io service the way I would [profile a CLI script](https://blackfire.io/doc/cli-tutorial) run via cronjob?

Comment: How are you running the worker?

Comment: @AlisterBulman beanstalkd daemon on Forge.